Best way for provisioning Content Types and Columns in SharePoint Online
There are many ways for provisioning columns and content types in SharePoint Online.
One could use Site Templates and Scripts, PnP Provisioning, create them via Code/PowerShell or just use the ContentType Hub.
Is the ContentType hub save to use? Or are there any downsides when comparing with the other methods mentioned?
I could imagine creating them once in the hub and then use them in Site Scripts for example. But is this working for every column type? Or should I better directly use some PnP Provisioning and create Site Columns like we did in SharePoint OnPrem?

Yes, you could use Content Type Gallery to reuse content types in the SharePoint online.
Content types created in the Content Type Gallery, when published, will be available to all sites and libraries in your SharePoint tenant. And it supports all column types.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/content-type-propagation

Thank you. Does it work reliably or are there any known bugs? For what is the "addContentTypesFromHub" action in site scripts if the content type from the Content Type Gallery is added to all Sites when published?
